# Error library Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have created a simple Simulink library because I am learning about masks. The library is saved into Documents folder, which is in path of MATLAB. To test my library, I've created a model and I've inserted my block from my library. When I want to change the value of a parameter in the mask I receive this error [screenshot of message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o4RQ.jpg)

Is there any configuration to do?

Thank you so much

Comment: What does the parameter do?  Does it make structural changes to the block? (Which isn't allowed.)

Comment: The parameter is a popup which I select to show the 2nd inport or replace it with a constant.

Comment: That sounds like a structural change ("or replace it"), which is not allowed when a block is in a library.